# How do you make a regex to select a pattern of X, Y or Z length

Tags: regex

If I need to find a regex that matches any positive number of lower case characters, an `N`, and then either 6 integers, 8 integers or 15 integers. But not match any other number of intagers

e.g. "abcN123456" or "abcdN12345678" or "abN123456789012345" or "abcdefgN123456"

How would you make a regex that finds this?

It starts with `[a-z]+N` but don't know how to do the variable number of integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
[a-z]+N(\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{15})
```

Comment: This regex returns a match for 7 integers (as it finds 6 then ignores the last int) is there a way around this?

Comment: you could add characters that follow the string (e.g. comma, whitespaces (\s) or quotes) or if the string end after that use `$` to end the regex like so: `[a-z]+N(\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{15})$`

Comment: Or `\b` to match the end of a word.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution

```
^[a-z]+N(?:\d{6}|\d{8}|\d{15})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/q7Eemgi2-dopxPI8)

or try this "crazier" variant ;)

```
^[a-z]+N(?:\d{6}|(?:(?:\d{7}){1,2}\d))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ApbAfvfiCqDvMHp7)

Comment: This regex returns a match for 7 integers (as it finds 6 then ignores the last int) is there a way around this?

Comment: "fixed" it by adding selectors for start & end